# Need help interpreting this code

Tags: r

So this code was handed out in our school, its one of many examples (model of  rolling a fair dice).

```
x<-runif(1)
y<-as.double(x<=c(1/6,2/6,3/6,4/6,5/6,1))*(1:6)
x<-min(y[y>0])
```

Im having trouble understanding the relation of this code and rolling a dice.

So the first line generates 1 randomly uniform distributed number x between 0 and 1. 
In the second line we put a condition into x: If its less than 1 of the components of the vector (1/6,2/6,3/6,4/6,5/6,1) we get a TRUE=1 , else FALSE=0.

And then this result is multiplied by the vector (1,2,3,4,5,6). 
Lastly we take the minimum value of that vector product (has to be greater than zero).

I cant get the intuition behind this. Would someone here mind to explain the relation of this code to rolling a dice in real life. Im confused..

Answer (score 1):

So for rolling a dice each number has the same probability of 1/6 to appear.

Now what is done here, is to simulate rolling a dice.

Therefore in the first line a random number between 0 and 1 is generated.

The intervals it is compared to are all equally sized and they have a length of 1/6. 
There for, for x to lie in one of these intervals the probability is again 1/6.
So what is done then in the third line, is to look up in which interval x has fallen.

Lets do an example: 
Supposed x is 0.25. 
Then the vector of the second line would look like this:

```
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE , TRUE, TRUE
```

With the multiplication you get:

```
0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Therefore at the end x is equal to 2.

So at the end x is supposed to be the number the dice is showing

Comment: So the things that makes me confused is:

1. Why does our random generated number x lie between 0 and 1? Could it have been in some other randomly chosen interval?

2. Why do we use the vector (1/6,2/6,3/6,4/6,5/6,1) ? And what do you mean with equally sized? Do you mean that 2/6-1/6=1/6 and 3/6-2/6=1/6 etc? That makes me still confused in the relationship to a dice.

3. And then we multiply this vector with (1,2,3,4,5,6) ? This vector looks like the outcomes of a dice? But why do we then choose the minmum of that vector product? Whats the reason behind that?

Comment: To answer your questions: 
1. yes, you could choose any other interval. What is important for simulating the dice, is that the unit distribution is applied. You could use the interval from 1 to 2 as well and separate it into 6 intervals of the same length.

2. That vector is used, due to your interval, the random number comes from. Yes, thats what I mean, each intervals there has a length of 1/6.

3. Is this question answered with the example?

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin is right basically your code is saying

If runif(1) = 0 to 1/6 = die roll = 1

runif(1) = 1/6 to 2/6 = die roll = 2

runif(1) = 2/6 to 3/6 = die roll = 3

etc

Because the second line returns a vector of results the x<-min(y[y>0])  just returns the first positive which is your die roll

Comment: Ok but why do we then choose the minmum of those values satisfying x<-min(y[y>0]) j ? Why couldnt it be another value chosen?

Comment: If you agree that x being between 2/6 and 3/6 means a roll of 3, which it does ( lets in fact say x is 3/6 so 0.5) on your second line of code we know that 4/6, 5/6 and 6/6(or 1) are all bigger than 3/6 so return TRUE when asking x>3/6,4/6,5/6 and 1 (remeber in R TRUE=1 and FALSE=0)  so you get: 0,0,1,1,1,1 which is multiplied by the die rolls(1,2,3,4,5,6) so the second line returns the die rolls 3,4,5,6 and we know if x is between 2/6 and 3/6 that the roll of 3 is the right choice, which is the minimum.